# Curl --insecure error in Cygwin (works in Linux)

Tags: cygwin, curl

Curl is returning an error in Cygwin.  How do I eliminate this error?

```
 curl --insecure -X POST -d '<run><log encoding="hexBinary">4142430A</log><result>0</result><duration>2000</duration></run>'   https://localhost:4444
```

The tunnel is working fine in Linux.  'Curl' in Cygwin returns the following error:
   `curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to https://localhost:4444`

--Insecure only appears to be working on Linux, not Cygwin.

Comment: Most likely an old or incomplete version of curl. What version of curl do you have and where did you get it?

Comment: Curl 7.29.0-1.  Installed with Cygwin, package "Net".

Comment: What is bound to port 4444?